# It's time for us to bring the CHAOS to Game Development

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Game developers! I'm Abby, a member of the fabled [CHAOS team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) at Stack Exchange. You might have seen me around if you hang out on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) ever - I'm in charge of the CHAOS mayhem on that site. Things are going well over there so far, so it's time for me to add another site to my portfolio. I picked Game Development, and here I am!

I'm going to start with a disclaimer - I know little to nothing about the technical aspects of game development. I am a gamer, though, and I'm interested in all the processes and steps that have to take place between waking up one morning with a great idea for a game and having people stay up all night trying to beat your brainchild. (Awkward wording, but you get the picture.)

I'll be working on general promotion ideas as well as attempting to personally recruit new kickass users. The first step is for me to embark on a title-editing-and-cleanup campaign. I'll be checking in on the homepage in the mornings and the evenings and making sure the titles are nice English sentences with correct punctuation, so noobs who show up here aren't too threatened. `<stage whisper>`*you guys can help with this if you want!*`</stage whisper>` I apologize in advance if this clogs up the moderator queue. If it gets annoying, please let me know, and I'll get myself some temporary mod privileges for while I'm doing the editing.

Okay. I've talked long enough. Time to make this post into a question:

What promotion ideas do you have? What sorts of things would you like to see us do?

Comment: I see you've been brutishly introduced to our automated greeting remover. ♪

Comment: @GraceNote Aye. I am chastised.

Comment: Recruit John Carmack :p That'd get us a lot of people ^^. Also, maybe help Attacking Hobo with planning this competition? Booth at GDC?

Comment: @Noctrine tell me more about Attacking Hobo? (Email me if you like.)

Comment: AttackingHobo is a user here, he is pretty common in chat and we have a room dedicated to discussing the competition we'd like to run. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/588/game-development-2-weekends-1-week-contest

Comment: @Noctrine aha! Thanks!

Comment: @Noctrine Whatever happened to that competition, anyway?

Comment: @Grace Hobo got really busy, and he is the primary organizer of it, he is looking to get moving with it again.

Comment: @Noctrine Great to hear! We're happy to be patient on Gaming, so just let us know when our part is time to shine. ♪

Answer (score 6):

The obvious conference-related promotional stuff could be to sponsor advertising at the various game developers' conferences.

The big organization that covers this is http://www.gdconf.com/  There's a big one in San Francisco, and smaller ones in Austin, China, and Europe.

Answer (score 0):

There are several indie game developer competitions going on, one way would be to sponsor them with prizes? This would be very beneficial for both parties as well.

Take **[Ludum Dare](http://ludumdare.com/)** for example.

Comment: Ludum Dare is a friendly competition, and isn't really the sort of thing that would benefit from prizes.  There might be benefit from offering them hosting (they had to upgrade servers during the recent competition), but I've no idea if they'd accept such an offer.

Comment: Yes, that is also a good idea, but don't forget that there are other competitions going on in several places that would love to be supported with prices. Ludum Dare was just an example as stated.